# how to install a driver like usb_cam

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have searched the sensor list on the:
http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors#Cameras

but i want know how to install it if i know the Source: git https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam.git (branch: master)

thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197651/how-to-install-a-driver-like-usb_cam/) by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-usb-cam`, replacing kinetic with your desired distribution. This will install the package to your `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib` directory.

---

Originally posted by [raunaks](https://answers.ros.org/users/35626/raunaks/) with karma: 26 on 2018-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-15**:
These days (sometime after ROS Indigo era), binary of [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) has been released, so I think this is more preferable answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Right now, Like you have mentioned the usb_cam has source code for wet build (catkin build). you just need to do the following to build it from source. (Note: I assume you are using ROS hydro or Indigo, It should work on groovy as well may be you can try it). But all that said, here you go:

`$ mkdir -p ~/catkin-ws/src`

`$ cd ~/catkin-ws/src`

`$ git clone https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam.git`

`$ cd ..`

`$ catkin_make`

`$ source ~/catkin-ws/devel/setup.bash`

after the above you can verify using ..

`$ roscd usb_cam`

roscore on a new terminal
`$ roscore`

and then in the terminal where you $ source 'd your usb_cam code run:

`$ rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node`

Make sure you have your camera connected, before running the above command!!! you view the captured image on rviz,

`$ rosrun rviz rviz`

hope this helps.
mk

---

Originally posted by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) with karma: 246 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on 2014-11-18**:
thank you very much ,i have  install it  success! it can give me the method to install other drivers ! !

**Comment by [R@m](https://answers.ros.org/users/25832/r@m/) on 2016-05-27**:
It worked for me as well. But I would like to connect to my usb cam that i have connected externally instead of my laptop's internal webcam... is there any way I could do that.???

**Comment by [GT](https://answers.ros.org/users/27012/gt/) on 2016-10-19**:
To connect external cam.
Locate the `usb_cam-test.launch` file in folder `cd ~/catkin-ws/src/usb_cam/launch`
Change `<param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />` to `<param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />` From `cd ~/catkin-ws/src/usb_cam/launch`.Run `roslaunch usb_cam-test.launch`

**Comment by [GT](https://answers.ros.org/users/27012/gt/) on 2016-10-20**:
See this one if u want to run more than one cam

```
http://answers.ros.org/question/218573/running-2-different-cameras-using-usb_cam/
```

**Comment by [michael_kong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29170/michael_kong/) on 2017-03-07**:
when I run  $ rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node, I got an error [ERROR] [1488942795.328150657]: outbuf size mismatch.  pic_size: 814080 bufsize: 614400.  But if I  run roslaunch usb_cam-test.launch directly, I could get the video. How could I fix that error?

**Comment by [dolphinlove](https://answers.ros.org/users/36122/dolphinlove/) on 2018-06-27**:
Well I have problem directly using `catkin_make`, and I solve it by type `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-usb-cam` first and then `catkin_make` again.